# NSTextField inside NSPopover is not key until mouse click

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nswindow, nspopover

I've got an NSPopover that is shown from interaction with an NSStatusItem.  I've blogged about the hacks I needed to do to make input even possible in this situation here: http://blog.brokenrobotllc.com/using-nspopover-with-nsstatusitem

I have an NSTextField inside the NSPopover's content view.  When I open the NSPopover, the NSTextField appears as if it is key (the cursor blinks).  But, when typing, nothing shows up.  If I click the mouse in the field, my input starts showing up there.

I've tried things like invoking NSWindow's makeFirstResponder upon popoverDidShow:.  There was no change in behavior from this.  Anyone have any ideas here?

Comment: So the `NSTextField` is inside a custom view (that is loaded by the `NSViewController` subclass)?  I have this with an `NSTextView` embedded in an `NSScrollView` (programatically created) and don't have this issue and I don't need to any tricks to make the `NSTextView` the first responder.

Answer (score 5):

My guess is you need to make your app active; try calling

```
[NSApp activateIgnoringOtherApps:YES];
```

when you show your popover.

Edit: Of course, I could be wrong. This is all just off the top of my head.

Comment: swift: `NSApplication.shared.activate(ignoringOtherApps: true)`