# Focus WKWebView in a NSPopover on open it

Tags: swift, wkwebview, nspopover

I'm making a [WKWebView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/webkit/wkwebview) in a [NSPopover](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nspopover) in [Swift](https://www.apple.com/swift/).
So when I open the NSPopover, the WKWebView is displayed.
That's good, now I'm trying to make the NSPopover close when I click outside so I added this line in the applicationDidFinishLaunching 's function :

```
popover.behavior = NSPopoverBehavior.transient;
```

But whith this one, the NSPopover only close if I click once on it. If i don't, the NSPopover will never close by click outside.
So the idea is : **how to focus the WKWebView (like when i click on it) when I open the NSPopover to avoid clicking on it before leaving ?**

This way can also solve a other problem, cause it's a WKWebView, the user have to click on it (to focus it) before be able to click on elements in the WKWebView). So if i can auto focus on WKWebView when the NSPopover, the problem may be solved.

Hope you understand :P
Thanks a lot ;)

Comment: Maybe this answer can lead you somewhere? https://stackoverflow.com/a/10706035/830604 - It worked in my case for using a NSPopover with a menubar app.